# Cocos2d-x: Hide Sprite in 1s

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm newbie in Cocos2d-x.

I'm developing a simple game.

I want to move a sprite from the right to the left.

During it moving, i want that sprite hide in a distance in 1s.
Sequence: 1s:visible,1s:invisible,1s:visible

Example: it run from position A to D
Between A and D we have B and C => ( A->B->C->D)
When sprite in A->B it visible, then B->C it'll be **hide**, then C->D it visible again.

How can i do it?

Thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 2):

For show/hide with delay you can use this code (I've wrote it right here, so it may not be compiled after simply copy and paste to your project =) )

```
float delay = 1f;
CCAction* hideAction = CCHide::create();
CCAction* showAction = CCShow::create();

CCActionInterval* showHideAction = CCSequence::create( CCDelayTime::create(delay),
                                                       hideAction,
                                                       CCDelayTime::create(delay),
                                                       showAction);
CCAction* foreverAction = CCRepeatForever::create(showHideAction);

yourNode->runAction(foreverAction);
```

To move your node(sprite in your case) you can use both `CCMoveTo` and `CCMoveBy` action.
For example

```
float moveDuration = 5f;
CCPoint targetPos = CCPointMake(someX, someY);
CCAction* moveAction = CCMoveTo::create(moveDuration, targetPos);

yourNode->runAction(moveAction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CCSpawn`, this can run two actions at the same time.

You can try this code:

```cpp
CCAction* action = CCSpawn::createWithTwoActions(CCMoveTo::create(1,CCPointMake(x,y)), 
                                                 CCFadeOut::create(1));
you_sprite->runAction(action);
```

**update:**

You can use `CCRepeatForever` to run fadein/fadeout, and after move action done, stop this forever action.

Here is the code:

```cpp
CCSequence* move = CCSequence::create(CCMoveTo::create(3, CCPointMake(1, 1)),
                                      CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(SomeClass::some_func)),
                                      NULL);
CCRepeatForever* forever = CCRepeatForever::create(CCSequence::create(CCFadeIn::create(1),
                                                                      CCFadeOut::create(1)
                                                                      NULL));
your_sprite->runAction(move);
your_sprite->runAction(forever);
```

Here is the callback function (invoked after move action);

```cpp
void SomeClass:some_func(){
  your_sprite->stopAllActions();
}
```

Comment: thank u so much, but i mean that: if it run 3s so it just invisible in 1s, Sequence: 1s:visible,1s:invisible,1s:visible

Answer (score 1):

Try this action

```
CCHide * hideAction = CCHide::create();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sprite->runAction(Sequence::create(MoveTo::create(1.0f, Vec2(200,200)),Hide::create(),MoveTo::create(1.0f, Vec2(200,400)),Show::create(),NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

SpriteName->runAction(Sequence::create(Hide::create(),NULL));

Here only Sprite Hide.